# Como mandar de volta a resposta do meu array para views?e aparecer dentro das td

Tags: php

//PASTA VIEWS

```
<?php
$botao="Sorteio";
$action="sorteio1";
?>
<!doctype - html5>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Array</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_home.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frmsorteio" method="post" action="router.php?controller=sorteio&modo=<?php echo($action)?>">
            <input class="botao1" type="submit" name="btn_prymari" value="<?php echo($botao)?>">
        <table class="tabela">
            <tr>
                <td class="colunas"></td>
                <td class="colunas"></td>
                <td class="colunas"></td>
```

//ROUTER.PHP

```
<?php

    $controller=$_GET['controller'];
    $modo=$_GET['modo'];

    switch($controller)
    {
        case 'sorteio':

            require_once('controllers/sorteio_controller.php');
            require_once('models/sorteio_class.php');

            switch($modo)
            {
                case 'sorteio1':
                    $controller_sorteio = new ControllerSorteio();
                    $controller_sorteio->Sorteio1();
                    break;
            }
    }

?>
```

//PASTA CONTROLLERS

```
<?php
 class ControllerSorteio{

        public function Sorteio1(){

            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
              require_once('models/sorteio_class.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

//PASTA MODEL

```
<?php
class CodeGen{
    private $codes = array();
    public function __construct($codes) {
        $this->codes = $codes;
}
    public function getRandomCode($min, $max){  
       $next = 60; 
            while (count($this->codes) < $next) {
                $code = mt_rand($min, $max);    
                if (!in_array($code, $this->codes)) {           
                    $this->codes[] = $code;   
         }      
    }   
}   
    public function getLastCode(){
        return ($this->codes);   
    }
}
    $codes = array();
    $CodeGen = new CodeGen($codes);
    $CodeGen->getRandomCode(0, 60);
    print_r $CodeGen->getLastCode();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito, pelo menos por enquanto, que seu código não precisa de um model, apenas uma view e um controller, mas deixando no mesmo padrão que esta fazendo:

View:

```
<?php
    session_start(); //função necessária para usar a variável global $_SESSION, deve ser chamada antes de qualquer outro código php

    $botao="Sorteio";
    $action="sorteio1";
?>
<!doctype - html5>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Array</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_home.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frmsorteio" method="post" action="router.php?controller=sorteio&modo=<?php echo($action)?>">
            <input class="botao1" type="submit" name="btn_prymari" value="<?php echo($botao)?>">
            <?php
                //Verifica se existe o array_sorteio e se ele não está vazio para criar a tabela
                if(isset($_SESSION["array_sorteio"]) && $_SESSION["array_sorteio"] != "") {
            ?>
                <table class="tabela">
                    <tr>
                        <?php 
                            $array = $_SESSION["array_sorteio"]; //Atribui a variável array o valor que está na sessão "array_sorteio"
                            unset($_SESSION["array_sorteio"]); //Destroi a posição "array_sorteio" da variável $_SESSION

                            for($i = 0; i < count($array); $i++) {
                                echo "<td>".$array[i]."</td>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

Router.php:

```
<?php
    session_start(); //função necessária para usar a variável global $_SESSION, deve ser chamada antes de qualquer outro código php

    $controller=$_GET['controller'];
    $modo=$_GET['modo'];

    switch($controller) {
        case 'sorteio':

            require_once('controllers/sorteio_controller.php');
            //require_once('models/sorteio_class.php'); - Retirar essa linha, o model vai ser inserido abaixo

            switch($modo) {
                case 'sorteio1':
                    $controller_sorteio = new ControllerSorteio();
                    //Aqui é inserido o model
                    if($controller_sorteio->Sorteio1()) {
                        //Se o model foi inserido..
                        $codes = array();
                        $CodeGen = new CodeGen($codes);
                        $CodeGen->getRandomCode(0, 60);
                        $array_sorteio = $CodeGen->getLastCode(); //Pega o array gerado no model e atribui a variável $array_sorteio

                        $_SESSION["array_sorteio"] = $array_sorteio; //Cria uma posição "array_sorteio" no array $_SESSION e atribui a ele o array gerado anteriormente
                        header("location: ./camiho/view.php"); //Envia o usuário para á pagina selecionada
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }

?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
    class ControllerSorteio {
        public function Sorteio1() {
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
                require_once('models/sorteio_class.php');

                //Cria um retorno para saber se o model foi (true) ou não (false) inserido
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
    class CodeGen {
        private $codes = array();

        public function __construct($codes) {
            $this->codes = $codes;
        }

        public function getRandomCode($min, $max){  
            $next = 60; 
            while (count($this->codes) < $next) {
                $code = mt_rand($min, $max);    
                if (!in_array($code, $this->codes)) {           
                    $this->codes[] = $code;   
                }      
            }   
        }   

        public function getLastCode(){
            return ($this->codes);   
        }
    }

    /* Esse bloco de código deve ser chamado dentro do router.php e não abaixo da classe do model
    $codes = array();
    $CodeGen = new CodeGen($codes);
    $CodeGen->getRandomCode(0, 60);
    print_r $CodeGen->getLastCode();
    */
?>
```

Não vou poder testar o código mas é mais ou menos isso (que eu faria) boa sorte, qualquer coisa é só perguntar

Comment: ok, já coloquei o codigo inteiro da models, só não entendi onde criarei a $_SESSION, na controllers?

Comment: ok, seu código está meio confuso e eu não vou poder montar uma resposta agora tenho que sair mas amanhã eu edito minha resposta e aviso. Quando fizer uma pergunta ou editar deixe seu código identado corretamente e com 4 espaços a mais no início de cada linha (para deixar no formato de bloco de código)

Comment: @Bruna editei a resposta com o modo que eu faria

Comment: Guilherme muito obrigada, o código ficou perfeito só precisei fazer alguma incrementações mas deu tudo certo, muito obrigada.

Comment: Se você sanou suas duvidas dessa pergunta, finalize com aceitando uma resposta

Answer (score -1):

Poderia fazer da seguinte maneira
Antes da tag Html, dentro da php:

```
try{
    require('conexao.php'); // Chama seu arquivo de conexão
    $sql = "Sua SCRIPT"; // Cria Script
    $stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql); //Prepara sua script com sua conexão
    $stmt->execute(); //Executa
}
catch(PDOExeption $e){
    echo " ".$e;
}
```

Depois da tag html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Array</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_home.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
  while($consulta = $stmt->fetch()){
?>
    <form name="frmsorteio" method="post" action="router.php?
 controller=sorteio&modo=<?php echo($action)?>">
        <input class="botao1" type="submit" name="btn_prymari" value="<?php 
 echo($botao)?>">
    <table class="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td class="colunas"><?php echo $consulta["nomecoluna"];?></td>
            <td class="colunas"><?php echo $consulta["nomecoluna2"];?></td>
            <td class="colunas"><?php echo $consulta["nomecoluna3"];?></td>
```

Não esqueça de fechar no depois da tag tr

```
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: Do modo como está, se a cunsulta retornar mais de uma linha, vai criar varioa formularios e tabelas em vez de só adicionar a linha, além disso a idéia  (pelo que posso ver do código) é manter as partes do mesmo separadas (arquivos com model, outros com o controller e outros com as view)

Comment: esta dando erro somente na variavel  #sql, não sei o que colocar no script

Comment: muito obrigada Gabriel